# Listen events of children templates in parent template

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor

I noticed an inconsistency in Meteor events listeners across differents browsers. I can listen events triggered in children templates on Chrome, but this doesn't works on Firefox and Safari (and probably IE, eh).

Here is minimal reproduction code :

```
Template.thisIsTheParent.events({
    'click .a-class-that-lives-in-children': function(e, t) {
        // Do something
    }
});

Template.thisIsAChildBetweenOthers.events({
    // On FF/Safari, I must put an event listener here on each children,
    // that leads to massive code duplication.
    'click .a-class-that-lives-in-children': function(e, t) {
        // Do something that the parent should do :/
    }
});
```

Spacebars (templating with `yield` is handled by Iron Router):

```
<template name="thisIsTheParent">
    <div>
        {{ > yield }}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="thisIsAChildBetweenOthers">
    <a class="a-class-that-lives-in-children">I want to handle the click on that in the parent</a>
</template>
```

On Chrome, the first event listener is called, but not in other browser. Is that an expected behavior ?

Comment: Done. There's really nothing more :)

Comment: Hold on, there isn't the router code. Could you instead replace `thisIsTheParent` with `body` and simply `{{ > childTemplate }}`?

Comment: Same with "direct render" :/